# How to validate time given in seconds rails 4

Tags: ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I know that I can use custom validation something like that:

```
validates :start_date, precense: true
validate :start_date

private
def start_date
  Time.at(@start_date)
rescue StandartError => e
  errors.add(:start_date, "start_date is incorrect!")
end
```

But it seems dirty a bit, is there a better way for that?

**update**

```
start_date = 628232400
Time.at(start_date) #=> 1989-11-28 00:00:00 -0500
```

Comment: What is the type of start_date?

Comment: @MaximPontyushenko edited my question

Comment: @AydarOmurbekov type of the column in database.

Comment: do you really need this validation. if your start date is not present? it will be catched by presence validation. if it present. and its type is integer it will always return some thing on this `Time.at(@start_date)`

Comment: @Зелёный I am not saving it in database, its just validation

Comment: If you just want to validate that `start_date` is a number, you can do `validates :start_date, numericality: true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try numericality option, since any number will work with Time.at(start_date). You might want to limit it to positive numbers only. There are couple options below.

```
validates :start_date, presence: true, numericality: true
```

or if you want to limit values:

```
validates :start_date, presence: true, numericality: {greater_than: 0, message: " is an invalid value."}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `validates_format_of`. But you will need a regular expression to match against. Read more [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_format_of).

You can also add a `format: {with: regex}` to your existing validation.